# how to draw points when i have an array of values and the coordinates depend of the indice

Tags: c++, opengl, shader

I have an array of 131072 values to draw in opengl with shaders. The coordinate of each point is calculated with the indice of the value, but i can't draw that. Now i have an error in the glDrawArrays.

This is part of my code set the vao and vbo, imagen is a CGfloat pointer with the data;

```
    int pixels = 131072;
    // Create vertex array objects
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    // Create vertex buffers
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);

    // VBO for coordinates of first square
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
             pixels * sizeof(GLfloat),
             imagen,
             GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, pixels, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

and this is my display function:

```
void display(void) {
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  glBindVertexArray(vao);
  glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 1);

  glBindVertexArray(0);
  glutSwapBuffers();
  glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

if i pass an array to shader how can handle the array to calculate the coordinates with the index of each value???

**Edit**

This is how calculate the coordinates of each point with the index of the array, if i have one cube of 64x64x32 pixels i do this:

```
XX = 64;
YY = 64;
ZZ = 32;

x = index % XX;
y = (index / XX) % YY;
z = (int) floor((double) index / (XX * YY));
```

And with the value of the each element of the array calculate the color of that point

**Edit 2**

This is the image that i get when i draw all points and i need fill this object and get a volume

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "the coordinate is calculated with the index"? Is it a simple lookup in the vertex buffer? Then you're probably looking for `glDrawElements()`.

Comment: `glVertexAttribPointer` only allows 1,2,3,4 as second parameter. Check the [reference](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml). In your case it should be 1 (one float per vertex).

Comment: If I understand your problem (which I probably do not), I think what you want is actually a texture. Drawing a large collection of `GL_POINTS` when you want to display an array of pixels is massively inefficient. A texture using an alpha channel to mask off the empty spaces may be more sensible.

Comment: @NicoSchertler I edit the post and add how i calculate the coordinates.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman how can use the texture in shader, you can explain me that??

Comment: Ok, then you're looking for instanced rendering. This will give you an instance id. You wouldn't even need a vertex buffer. The color could be saved in a texture. If you want to draw a volume, take a look at existing volume rendering strategies.

Comment: @NicoSchertler i add the image that i get and need to fill and get a volume